# Regex that can capture part of string like "letter+whitespace+letter+whitespace..."

Tags: regex

I need a pattern to remove part of string like "letter+whitespace+letter+whitespace..." till first dot. For example, in string

> D o c t o r. I'll give you a prescription.

pattern should match *"D o c t o r. "* 
   Now I have a pattern `([A-Za-z]\s?)+\.` But it matches more substrings that I need. Any ideas how to correct it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you elaborate on what it matches that you don't want it to match?

Comment: Do you really need to match any whitespace or just a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require a word boundary before each letter the whitespace will be required between the letters. Right now, consecutive letters can be matched as the whitespace pattern is optional (1 or 0 occurrences).

So, you may just use

```
(\b[A-Za-z]\s?)+\.
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uODaJy/1)

Or, alternatively, use

```
\b[A-Za-z](?:\s[A-Za-z])+\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uODaJy/2). Here,

- `\b` -  matches the leading word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]` - a letter
- `(?:\s[A-Za-z])+` - 1 or more (**NOTE** if you also want to match 1-letter + dot sequences, replace `+` with `*` quantifier) consecutive occurrences of

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `[A-Za-z]` - a letter
- `\.` - a dot.